# Overriding default make target

Tags: git, makefile

There is a project where running `make` (which triggers the default target in `Makefile` stored in `git`) is the advised method of building it. I have muscle memory to typing `make` so I don't want to change what I type.

How do I override just the default target of running `make`?

I know I can just modify `Makefile` and then add it to `.gitignore` but this will hinder my ability to do other modifications to `Makefile` that needs to be committed, so I hope I don't need to modify `Makefile` itself.

I also hope I don't need to `alias make` to something else because I probably need to run `make` for other open source projects.

Comment: You can add a tracked file to `.gitignore` but it doesn't do anything (it won't make it ignore changes). You need to use `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of a hacky answer, but I'm not sure if a clean one exists. From the `make` man page:

> If no -f option is  present, make  will  look for the makefiles GNUmakefile, makefile, and Makefile, in that order.

So you could copy the current makefile into `GNUmakefile` (or just lowercase `makefile` if your filesystem is case-sensitive and/or you aren't running the GNU version of make), then make your edits there (specifying new targets) and when you type `make`, the new `GNUmakefile` or `makefile` would run instead of the project's own `Makefile`, because `make` would look for it first.

Comment: No need to copy the file actually if you don't mind an extra make process. See [Overriding Part of Another Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding-Makefiles).

Comment: Yeah, no need to copy. I just put two lines there and it works: `default: target-to-trigger` and then `include Makefile`.